# How to keep spacing uniform in <ul> with different numbers of <li> elements in different rows

Tags: html, css, text-align

At the last row, the spaces among li elements are not same as the previous rows. I want all of them to be same. I do not want to use text-align: center, because it ruins the alignment between the li elements at the last row and the li elements at the upper rows. My code is:

```
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
li {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    direction: ltr;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use grid instead of setting inline-blocks and justifying.

```html
<style>
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    rtext-align: justify;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  li {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    direction: ltr;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

(I switched to using placeholder.com as the original image took time to load).

Comment: That is really helpful to align the last row, but it doesn't align li elements to the center. To be more clear, observe that the white rightmost vertical gap's bigger than the leftmost one in your code. I wonder how to align all of the li elements to the center, making rightmost and leftmost gaps to be equal in size. Consider:
```
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;} 
li{
 direction: ltr;
 width: 320px;
 display: inline-block;}
```
Here the gaps are equal, in addition to that, i want the last row elements to be aligned with the upper row elements as you did

Comment: @lapin just to make sure I am clear, you want the far left gap and the far right gap to be the same as the gaps in the middle? Is that correct? Do you want each li to be 300px wide or not - is it the gaps between the images that are important rather than the width of each li being considerably larger?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
  
li {
  direction: ltr;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <title>question</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="question.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x90" alt="stack"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for inspiration.

Comment: So having a colmn otside the viewport didn't matter?